# swift 4 model class error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: swift, class, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a model class for notes that have the attributes title and content. I am getting an error in the second init that says: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties. Im feel like there is something I am missing and I cant seem to see it. This is the code:

```
class Note{
private var _title: String
private var _content: String

var title: String!{
    return self._title
}

var content: String!{
    return self._content
}

init(title: String, content: String){
    self._title = title
    self._content = content
}

init(noteData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {


    if let title = noteData["title"] as? String {
        self._title = title
    }

    if let content = noteData["content"] as? String {
        self._content = content
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The if statement in the init(nodeData) need else clauses for default values if you want to write your code this way. Also, you shouldn't use _ for variables in Swift

Comment: See [Two-Phase initialization.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialise all properties of your class in its initializer. Regarding your dictionary initializer you should make it fallible and return nil in case of missing key/value pairs:

```
class Note {
    let title: String
    let content: String
    init(title: String, content: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let content = dictionary["content"] as? String
        else { return nil }
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Note that if use a struct instead of a class you don't even have to implement an initializer for your custom object:

```
struct Note {
    let title: String
    let content: String
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let content = dictionary["content"] as? String
            else { return nil }
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the second init, if the unwrap fails the properties will not be set. For the init to work correctly the properties that are not optional will all need values. The best way to fix this is to make the properties optional.

Optional properties:

```
private var title: String?
private var content: String?
```

By making the properties optional you can avoid doing the if let in the init:

```
self.title = noteDate["title"]
```

Make sure to unwrap safely when you use the properties though!